# Rebinding C-c to C-c

Tags: emacs, viper, viper-mode

I'm using Viper, and I want to change its `C-c` and `C-g` to the original emacs functions. I can rebind `C-g` with `(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map "C-g" 'keyboard-quit)`, but how can I rebind `C-c`, since it's a prefix key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may make sense for you to run <kbd>M-x viper-set-expert-level</kbd> with an argument of 2 ("Master").  As the `viper-mode` documentation explains:

> **2** -- **MASTER**: <kbd>C-c</kbd> now has its standard
>   Emacs meaning in Vi command state, so
>   most Emacs commands can be used when
>   Viper is in Vi state.

As you master `viper-mode`, you're meant to increase your expert-level setting gradually over time, making more Emacs features available to you (or, as the Viper documentation puts it, "To use Emacs productively, you must reach level 3 or higher").

Answer (score 2):

The original binding for <kbd>C-c</kbd> can be set with the following:

```
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map (kbd "C-c") 'mode-specific-command-prefix)
```

The info page for this is [Prefix Keys](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html).